# GUI won't load properly after update 19.04

Tags: grub2, 19.04, gui

After upgrading to 19.04 my gui no longer loads normally. After booting I get stuck on a purple screen (with some distortion). Booting in recovery mode however goes really smoothly.

The kernel has the following error messages:

```
dmesg -l err         
[    4.877660] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -6
[    4.879379] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -6
[   80.431815] debugfs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
[   80.431819] debugfs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
[   80.907771] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

Are any of these error messages relevant to my issue? Why are things working in recovery  mode, but not in regular mode?

Answer (score 0):

Software Updater --> Settings... --> Additional drivers --> NVIDIA: Change using X.Org X server to NVIDIA driver from nvidia-driver-435, fixed my issue.