# Taking 1 minute on an SSD and these messages appear before opening the system

Tags: indicator-message

after a long time without using Linux and Ubuntu I reinstalled it on my machine, boot is taking 1 minute on an SSD and these messages appear before opening the system. I just formatted and updated it. Can anyone tell me what could be happening?

My setup: Ryzen 5 3600 and RTX 2070 super, 16GB RAM

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: Some settings to reveiw and links to even more: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Maybe a newer firmware might help, but be careful, wrong firmware files can make your system unbootable: [Kernel org Firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/)

Comment: 2nd pix is not adding any useful info (all are OK/green, no red lines). Please do not add pictures and add TEXT. See this duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278399/dual-system-ubuntu-20-04nvidia-gpu-i2c-timeout-error-ucsi-ccg-i2c-transfer and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264037/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-with-kernel-5-4-ic2-timeout-error  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186350/gui-wont-load-properly-after-update-19-04